# JButton Drag and Drop

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jbutton, jcomponent

I am developing an editor and I need to know how to apply drag and drop over jbutton, so I can drag it into another jcomponent and drop it smoothly, thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to do? What is going to happen then?

Comment: Thank you dear for replying, if you are using win7, what i need to do is just like what is done when you dragging any icon on the taskbar the other icons will be shifted to allow you to insert the dragged icon between to other ones. if you dont I will send you a video illustrate what I mean. thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All What I have to do are: override paint method, use mouseDragged and mouseMoved events such as in the following [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/draggable-java.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JButton b = new JButton("Button");

String propertyName = "MyButton";
label.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler(propertyName));

label.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        JComponent c = (JComponent)evt.getSource();
        TransferHandler handler = c.getTransferHandler();
        th.exportAsDrag(c, e, TransferHandler.COPY);
    }
});
```

Comment: I appreciate your reply, but I really didnt got it, I need some in depth explanation and not so general such as what is illustrated at Oracle documentation because I am new in dealing with swing component, thank you so much